# Debug Python code thats in a PIP package in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My debugging is setup in VS code, I can hit break points in the file I'm running via the launch.json config, but I can't get breakpoints in packages that are installed with PIP. How do I get breakpoints in these package files?

Comment: If you are going to try altering source code of the packages even if you are just adding a break point I strongly recommend doing it on a virtual environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know where you python installation is on your computer do this:

1. Know where you python packets were installed.
2. File -> add folder to workspace
3. Add the breakpoints where necessary.

As an alternative i would advise to create a virtual environment and do the same thing but with the safety of virtual environment. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to File -> Add folder to workspace I had to add this line to `launch.json`

```
"justMyCode": false
```

Comment: You saved me a day. Thanks.